# Backbone.js Bootstrapping collections: How much is too much?

Tags: backbone.js, bootstrapping

In Backbone when bootstrapping collections, how do I determine what is too much? Would it be a bad idea to bootstrap 10,000 member records and 300,000 photo records? I'm not sure how to decide how much is too much.

Comment: I am still learning backbone.js, so forgive me if my question does not make sense, but can you clarify what do you mean by bootstrapping records? Do you mean preparing bootstrap.js Collections data structures to be downloaded with the initial page request instead than getting data later with ajax? If so this could be a wider question, not necessarily limited to bootstrap but to Javascript memory management more in general.

Comment: Lazy load. Anything over a couple of hundred records is overkill. Even a couple of hundred may be too much.

Comment: @Anubi "Do you mean preparing bootstrap.js Collections data structures to be downloaded with the initial page request instead than getting data later with ajax" That's what we do and that's my understanding of the question as well. Our framework populates an object with some of the data and the scripts that bootstrap our app create models and collections based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're doing is displaying the content, just bootstrap enough to fill a generous size page and lazy load the rest. If you're doing something interactive (e.g. sorting or filtering) in the browser, then you might still be able to get away with that strategy, provided that

- users will typically want to at least glance at the data for a few seconds before activating a sort or filter, and
- your server is fast enough to fill in the remaining items (after the first "page-full") in that time.

Comment: Yeah this makes perfect sense. I kinda figured my numbers were too high and that something like this would be the answer. Needed to hear it from someone smarter than me. Thanks :-)